# Django multidb with router - cannot insert during tests

Tags: python, django, pytest

I have a multiple databases application and a DB router, but somehow insert is not working during test.
here is my settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        # HOST, PORT, NAME, USER, PASSWORD
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': 'test__db',
            'CHARSET': 'utf8',
            'COLLATION': 'utf8_general_ci',
        }
    },
    'default_replica': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        # HOST, PORT, NAME, USER, PASSWORD
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': 'test__db_replica',
            'CHARSET': 'utf8',
            'COLLATION': 'utf8_general_ci',
        }
    },
    'reporting': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        # HOST, PORT, NAME, USER, PASSWORD
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': 'test__reporting',
            'CHARSET': 'utf8',
            'COLLATION': 'utf8_general_ci',
        }
    },
    'reporting_replica': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        # HOST, PORT, NAME, USER, PASSWORD
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': 'test__reporting_replica',
            'CHARSET': 'utf8',
            'COLLATION': 'utf8_general_ci',
        }
    },
}
```

my router.py:

```
class Router:

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):

        if model._meta.label_lower in settings.DB_REPORTING_MODELS:
            return 'reporting_replica'

        if model._meta.label_lower in settings.DB_FORCE_READ_MODELS:
            return 'default_replica'

        return 'default'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):

        if model._meta.label_lower in settings.DB_REPORTING_MODELS:
            return 'reporting'

        return 'default'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):

        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):

        if model_name is None:
            return None

        model_id = f'{app_label}.{model_name}'

        if db == 'reporting' and model_id in settings.DB_REPORTING_MODELS:
            return True
        elif db == 'default':
            return True

        return None
```

my test function:

```
def insert():
    a = ModelName.objects.create(value='test')
    return a
```

and my test:

```
def test_insert(self):
    assert not ModelName.objects.exists()
    a = insert()

    assert a

    b = ModelName.objects.first()

    assert a == b
```

second assert fails because `b` is None, but when i remove DATABASE_ROUTERS from settings it starts working in tests(while application is running both cases create a DB entry)